# How to bundle httpie with httpie-aws-authv4 into Python zipapp?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, httpie, zipapp

It is straightforward to package [httpie](https://httpie.org) into a Python "PYZ" (zipapp), e.g. using

```
$ pip install --upgrade zapp
$ zapp httpie.pyz httpie.__main__:main httpie
$ python ./httpie.pyz --version
1.0.3
```

Now I tried to include [httpie-aws-authv4](https://github.com/aidan-/httpie-aws-authv4) as a plug-in to httpie, for AWS authentication. Alas, `httpie` does not pick up that plug-in.

```
$ zapp httpie-aws4.pyz httpie.__main__:main httpie httpie-aws-authv4
$ python ./httpie-aws4.pyz       
usage: http [--json] [--form] [--pretty {all,colors,format,none}]
...   
            [--auth USER[:PASS]] [--auth-type {basic,digest}]

$ python ./httpie-aws4.pyz -A aws4 http://localhost:9200/
...
http: error: argument --auth-type/-A: invalid choice: u'aws4' (choose from 'basic', 'digest')
```

It should say `[--auth-type {basic,digest,aws4}]`

Anyone knows how to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I worked around the plug-in loading issue by registering the extension with the built-in list of authentication mechanisms. This makes the plug-in available and operational, albeit through a different mechanism. For the zipapp use this is perfectly fine:

```
zapp httpie-aws4.pyz httpie.__main__:main httpie httpie-aws-authv4
mkdir -p httpie/plugins
unzip -q -c httpie-aws4.pyz httpie/plugins/__init__.py | gsed \
      -e '15i from httpie_aws_authv4 import AWSv4AuthPlugin # ADDED' \
      -e '19i AWSv4AuthPlugin, # ADDED' \
> httpie/plugins/__init__.py
zip httpie-aws4.pyz httpie/plugins/__init__.py
```

The `aws4` authentication mechanims then appears, as desired:

```
python ./httpie-aws4.pyz 2>&1 | grep auth-type
            [--auth USER[:PASS]] [--auth-type {aws4,basic,digest}]
```